Binary Classification on a Medical dataset (SVM)
I am working on a project involving the usage of machine learning models to classify a given medical dataset. The dataset, wich you can find here: https://zenodo.org/records/10885957, contains 10.000 patients data. Each patient has 39 features and the target column is binary, 1 means post op. complications, 0 means no post op. complications.
The first thing we did is to check for missing values or repeated rows. In this case there's none. Then we checked for data distribution, 75% is in the class 0, the remaining 25% is in class 1. The dataset is pretty unbalanced if this is the distribution right?
For now we did not act on the fact that classes are unbalanced.
After this first analysis we did a train_test_split with test size equal to 0.2. The dataset presents different kind of features so in order to use a StandardScaler we separated the features in two big groups (both in training and testing dataframes). The first group (the one to use the scaler on) is composed by "continous" features like sodium concentration or percentage of white blood cells etc... in the second group there are features like age,sex and other data coming from surveys and such.
We applied the standard scaler on the training using .fit_transform and on the test using .transform.
X_train, X_test = train_test_split(dataset, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)
y_train = X_train['Complications']
y_test = X_test['Complications']
X_train = X_train.drop(['Complications'],axis=1)
X_test = X_test.drop(['Complications'],axis=1)
X_continous_tr = pd.concat([X_train.iloc[:,0:6].reset_index(drop=True),X_train.iloc[:,17:37].reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
X_discrete_tr = pd.concat([X_train.iloc[:,6:17].reset_index(drop=True),X_train.iloc[:,37:40].reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
X_continous_ts = pd.concat([X_test.iloc[:,0:6].reset_index(drop=True),X_test.iloc[:,17:37].reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
X_discrete_ts = pd.concat([X_test.iloc[:,6:17].reset_index(drop=True),X_test.iloc[:,37:40].reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_continous_tr_sc = scaler.fit_transform(X_continous_tr)
X_continous_tr_sc = pd.DataFrame(X_continous_tr_sc)
X_continous_ts_sc = scaler.transform(X_continous_ts)
X_continous_ts_sc = pd.DataFrame(X_continous_ts_sc)
X_train = pd.concat([X_continous_tr_sc.reset_index(drop=True),X_discrete_tr.reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
X_test = pd.concat([X_continous_ts_sc.reset_index(drop=True),X_discrete_ts.reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
X_train.columns = X_train.columns.astype(str)
X_test.columns = X_test.columns.astype(str)

At this point are there any possibilities of data leakage?
We tried to use some Kernels, just to see how a model would behave on the dataset.
First we tried a linear kernel:
svm = SVC(kernel='linear', C=0.001)
svm.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = svm.predict(X_test)
p = svm.predict(X_train)
print("Accuracy on test (Linear Kernel):", accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("Accuracy on train (Linear Kernel):", accuracy_score(y_train, p))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_train, p))

and the results are the following:
Accuracy on test (Linear Kernel): 0.977
Accuracy on train (Linear Kernel): 0.9798571428571429
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.97      1.00      0.98      2245
           1       1.00      0.91      0.95       755

    accuracy                           0.98      3000
   macro avg       0.99      0.95      0.97      3000
weighted avg       0.98      0.98      0.98      3000

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.97      1.00      0.99      5325
           1       1.00      0.92      0.96      1675

    accuracy                           0.98      7000
   macro avg       0.99      0.96      0.97      7000
weighted avg       0.98      0.98      0.98      7000

Can a result like this be considered overfitting? The accuracy on the train and the one on the test are pretty high and similar, and also the different scores are high in both cases.
We then proceeded with all the other types of kernels, gettin a perfect 1.0 score with the rbf kernel.
Is something wrong here? Is the dataset too easy for the models? Or we are not seeing something important here?
NOTE: The only kernel that gewts poor results (57% acc) is the sigmoid Kernel.

It seems the data is very simple. You have not done OHE for categorical features otherwise you could have got 100% accuracy.
Few columns e.g. Sodium', Urea_Nitrogen, INR etc. have very high correlation with the target. See this below plot of sodium and Urea_Nitrogen with the Target


I hope the following tips will help make your model more general:

Use stratification:

X = dataset.drop(['Class'], axis=1)
y = dataset['Class']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)


Create validation set:

X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_test, y_test, stratify=y_test, test_size=0.5, random_state=1)


Trainset (70%), Valset (15%), Test(15%)


Use Valset for cross-validation:
For example: Stratified k-fold is good baseline.

These are the basic things that help prevent overtraining.
